# How do I pas instances, created in a class method, to another method in the same class?

Tags: java, variables

I've created this Class:

```
class File {
    public String path;
    public int numberOfLines = 0;
    public String[] fileContent;

    public File (String file_path) {
         path = file_path;
    }

    public BufferedReader openFile () throws IOException {
        FileReader ReadFile = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader ReadFilePerLine = new BufferedReader(ReadFile);
    }    
    public int countLines () {
        String line;

        while((line = ReadFilePerLine.readLine()) != null){
            numberOfLines++;
        }
        return numberOfLines;
    } 
    public String[] readLines () {
        String[] fileContent = new String[numberOfLines];
        for (int i=0; i < numberOfLines; i++){
            fileContent[i] = ReadFilePerLine.readLine();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get the `countLines()` method to know of the existence of `ReadFilePerLine` and how do I get him to use it? (same for the `numberOfLines` variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BufferedReader ReadFilePerLine = new BufferedReader(ReadFile);`

this is a local variable of the `openFile()` method, and therefore exists only within the scope of that method.

If you want it to be accessible to other methods, make it an instance variable (i.e. move `BufferedReader ReadFilePerLine;` to be outside the method).

Answer (score 0):

You should use method arguments for that, like this:

```
public int countLines (BufferedReader in) {
    String line;

    while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
        numberOfLines++;
    }
    return numberOfLines;
}
```